# Writing String To File While Exporting Database Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a field called ACTION_TYPE. The potential values for it are "ADD   ", "Change", "DELETE", and "-". I want to export the rows which have an ACTION_TYPE value that isn't "-". I'm successfully exporting the table row in the correct format to the file, however the headers aren't working/ being written.

Basically what I want is to separate the entries by the type in the file. In example

```
ADD
00           00      56               55
00           00      59               42
00           00      36               45
CHANGE
00           00      96               25
DELETE
00           00      76               75
00           00      38               95
```

So far I've been unsuccessful in even getting it to work with ADD. Also, when I do get it working with one of the three types, is there a better way than just cloning the process for each type (ADD, CHANGE, DELETE)?

```
using (StreamWriter writer =
                    new  StreamWriter("C:\\BillingExport\\EXPORTS\\EFTHLDAY.TABLE.TYPE08.TRANSACTIONS.txt"))
                    {
                        writer.Write("ADD");
                    }
                    string selectCommandText42 = "SELECT * FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE WHERE ACTION_TYPE = 'ADD   '";
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter42 = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText42, connection))
                    {
                        using (DataTable table42 = new DataTable("HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE"))
                        {
                            adapter42.Fill(table42);
                            System.Text.StringBuilder commaDelimitedText = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                            //commaDelimitedText.AppendLine("col1,col2,col3"); // optional if you want column names in first row
                            foreach (DataRow row in table42.Rows)
                            {
                                string value = string.Format("{0}                  {0}         {1}                 {2}", row[1], row[2], row[3]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)                                   
                                commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
                            }
                                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\BillingExport\\EXPORTS\\EFTHLDAY.TABLE.TYPE08.TRANSACTIONS.txt",     commaDelimitedText.ToString());                              
                        }
                    }
```

**Update:** Implementing some of the suggestions below, I now have the following code

```
string selectCommandText42 = "SELECT * FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE WHERE ACTION_TYPE != '-'";
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter42 = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText42, connection))
                    {
                        using (DataTable table42 = new DataTable("HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE"))
                        {
                            adapter42.Fill(table42);
                            System.Text.StringBuilder commaDelimitedText = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                            //commaDelimitedText.AppendLine("col1,col2,col3"); // optional if you want column names in first row

                            foreach (DataRow row in table42.Rows)
                            {
                                string rowtype = row[4].ToString();
                                using (StreamWriter writer =
                                                                new StreamWriter("C:\\BillingExport\\EXPORTS\\EFTHLDAY.TABLE.TYPE08.TRANSACTIONS.txt")){
                                writer.WriteLine(rowtype);
                            }
                                string value = string.Format("{0}                  {0}         {1}                 {2}", row[1], row[2], row[3]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)                                   
                                commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
                            }
                            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\BillingExport\\EXPORTS\\EFTHLDAY.TABLE.TYPE08.TRANSACTIONS.txt", commaDelimitedText.ToString());                              
                        }
                    }
```

This is providing the following output

```
ADD
00           00      96               25
00           00      76               75
00           00      38               95
00           00      56               55
00           00      59               42
00           00      36               45
```

It seems to not be applying the CHANGE or DELETE headers, and is also not listing entries in the appropriate order (the ADD entries are at the bottom of the created file now).

Comment: A much faster and easier solution would be to use SSIS and export the results of your queries to a CSV file. This will also avoid loading everything in memory before writing it back to the disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a *much* better way that does not require:

1. duplicating code
2. pulling in the entire result set into memory (i.e. the `DataTable`)
3. duplicating the entire result set in memory again but in the form of a `StringBuilder`

The general concept is:

1. Query for all of the data you want in a single SELECT. You can do this by matching your require of

   > ACTION_TYPE value that isn't "-"

   by using a WHERE clause of `WHERE ACTION_TYPE <> '-'`
2. Sort the results so that you get them in the intended order of "ADD", then "CHANGE", then "DELETE". You can do this by adding a simple `ORDER BY ACTION_TYPE ASC`
3. Loop through `SqlDataReader.Read()` and do a "control break" (I'm sure the concept goes by various names) to apply the new header IF the value of the current row for `ACTION_TYPE` is different from the previous row.
4. Write each line out to the file as it is processed. Use [StreamWriter.WriteLine(String, Object, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dxte882.aspx) to output the line while formatting it at the same time.

Please note:

- You might need to adjust the index value of the `_Reader.GetString` call as I have no insight into the schema and am not sure which column is `ACTION_TYPE`
- It is recommended to explicitly SELECT the fields by name, rather than using `SELECT *`.
- By prefixing a string with `@` it won't translate escape sequences and hence no need for double-backslashes in file paths :)

The code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string _CurrentActionType = "";

SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand(
                            @"SELECT *
                                FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE
                                WHERE ACTION_TYPE <> '-'
                                ORDER BY ACTION_TYPE ASC;",
                            _Connection
                          );
SqlDataReader _Reader = null;

try
{                         
   _Connection.Open();

   _Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();

   if (_Reader.HasRows())
   {
      using (StreamWriter writer =
            new StreamWriter(
               @"C:\BillingExport\EXPORTS\EFTHLDAY.TABLE.TYPE08.TRANSACTIONS.txt"))

      {
         while (_Reader.Read())
         {
            // assuming [ACTION_TYPE] field is 5th column; adjust accordingly
            if (_Reader.GetString(4) != _CurrentActionType)
            {
               _CurrentActionType = _Reader.GetString(4);
               writer.WriteLine(_CurrentActionType);
            }

            writer.WriteLine(
               "{0}                  {0}         {1}                 {2}",
               _Reader.GetInt32(1), _Reader.GetInt32(2), _Reader.GetInt32(3));
         }
      }
   }
}
finally
{
   _Reader.Close();
   _Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: @bob-francis please use comments to post messages. Message was: I have tried implementing this, although it had a lot of errors for me. I've made some adjustments, and now I'm just left with 3 errors, which is the 3 instances of the row[] calls (the name row does not exist in the current context).

Comment: I changed row[1] to _Reader[1], 2 etc. Tested and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @bob-francis : I have updated the code to swap `row[]` for `_Reader.GetInt32()`. Sorry about that. Are these fields really INT values? If not, the `GetXXXX()` can be easily changed to fit the appropriate data type.

Comment: @BobFrancis : great! I think the syntax I just updated to is preferred. The only other thing I left out was the appropriate `using` references for the libraries. But it seems that you figured that out :).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) in your loop, you're overwriting previous changes:

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file.
>
> If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, as it will *not* overwrite your file:

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file.

Modified code:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\BillingExport\EXPORTS\EFTHLDAY.TABLE.TYPE08.TRANSACTIONS.txt",
                   commaDelimitedText.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to use DataSet.
sql command will be something like

```
var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE WHERE ACTION_TYPE = 'ADD'; 
                SELECT * FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE WHERE ACTION_TYPE = 'CHANGE';
                SELECT * FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE WHERE ACTION_TYPE = 'DELETE';"
```

and then load it to DataSet and refer via Tables property

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e594f9e-98b2-4a47-a87f-a5151e0c7828/loading-multiple-tables-within-dataset-in-single-call-c

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Query ordering by the ACTION_TYPE:

```
"SELECT * FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE WHERE ACTION_TYPE IN ('ADD   ', 'DELETE   ', 'Change  ') ORDER BY ACTION_TYPE ASC"
```

Then, apply this logic in your LOOP:

1) Save the first Type you encounter, and write it:

```
string rowtype = table42.Rows[0].Item("ACTION_TYPE");   
writer.Write(rowtype);
```

2) Check when the type change, and write it only when it changes:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in table42.Rows)
   {
        if (row.Item("ACTION_TYPE").ToString() != rowtype)
        {
            commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(rowtype);
        }   
        string value = string.Format("{0}                  {0}         {1}                 {2}",      row[1], row[2], row[3]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)                                   
        commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
   }
```

3)

To write your file, use File.AppendAllText:

```
File.AppendAllText(_YOURFILEHERE_, commaDelimitedText.ToString());
```

I wrote it without trying, it might work